# Left join with two exclusive conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, multiple-conditions

I have two tables V and E and I need to do a strange LEFT JOIN.

In the E table there are the columns:

- COD_Obj that has 6 letters
- COD_P that has 3 letters

In the V table there is a column:

- O_OR_P that as can have mutually exclusively

  - an Obj that has 9 letters and matches its first 6 letters with E.COD_Obj
  - a P that 12 letters and matches its last 3 letters with E.COD_P

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT DSC,
COUNT(IIF([Cost] IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL)) AS [N Cost]
, INT(SUM(IIF([Cost] IS NOT NULL, [Cost], 0))) AS [Total Cost]
, INT(SUM(IIF([Fees] IS NOT NULL, Fees, 0))) AS [Total Fees]
 LEFT JOIN E ON LEFT(V.P_OR_O,6)=E.COD_Obj 
  OR RIGHT(V.P_OR_O,3)=E.COD_P
 GROUP BY DSC
ORDER BY DSC
```

It does the grouping correct, but each group returns TOO MUCH of N Cost, Total Cost, and Total Fees. I suspect there are things repeated on the result of this query.

And if I change the OR of the LEFT JOIN to be an AND, I will see only one line, corresponding to only one group.

I am dazzled and confused. Please help on how to do a match with two alternative criteria. And, before you ask, yes, the V.P_OR_O field can have empty/null values.

And no, I can't change the data model at this moment because, people depends on this database and I can not control the Server to redefine the database structure.

The tables are both in SQL server and I am using Microsoft Office's Access to query against them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a length into your join condition, something like this:

```
SELECT 
DSC
, COUNT(IIF([Cost] IS NOT NULL, 1, NULL)) AS [N Cost]
, INT(SUM(IIF([Cost] IS NOT NULL, [Cost], 0))) AS [Total Cost]
, INT(SUM(IIF([Fees] IS NOT NULL, Fees, 0))) AS [Total Fees]
FROM V
LEFT JOIN 
E 
ON   (LEFT(V.P_OR_O,6)=E.COD_Obj AND LEN(IIF(ISNULL(P_OR_O),'',P_OR_O)) = 9)
  OR (RIGHT(V.P_OR_O,3)=E.COD_P AND LEN(IIF(ISNULL(P_OR_O),'',P_OR_O)) = 12)
GROUP BY DSC
ORDER BY DSC
```

Comment: I corrected the query because it didn't work. ISNULL in Access has a different meaning: it says whether the value is null or not. And I removed the links because they pointed to documentation that is not corresponding

Comment: Altought the values now are a little lower, the query still gives me values greater than it should!

Comment: Try removing the summations and the group by, run it into excel and see where it's wrong. The query looks fine to me, so there's either a problem with your data or your description of the data. If table V has the values and you only want values that have entries in table E, switch the order of the join `FROM E LEFT JOIN V`

Comment: No. I want all the values of V, even if they don't match an entry in E. But if I do this query without the part beginning in the LEFT JOIN against the V table, the sum of values is lesser than if I execute as it is itself.